# How do I get an object reference from within a static callback function?

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c++

I have a static callback function which is supposed to set an `NSString` and then call an `updateLabelWithString:` type function over in another file.

How do I get a reference to that file (my `AppDelegate`, if that helps) from within my static c++ function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have a reference to that object. You could set a static global and stash the reference into that, prior to your static method being called.

First though, I'd try to just use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`. You can call Objective-C methods from static C functions. Not sure if this works from C++ though.